# AzureAd authentication - STATELESS (Spring Boot Java)

Tags: java, spring-security, azure-active-directory, swagger

I have a project with AAD authentication, everything works fine until I add the following code to my HttpSecurity config

```java
    http
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and();
```

Application starts asking to login again and again in endless cycle.

If I remove that part of code - the app works as expected but there are issues with swagger.
Looks like swagger reads cached authorization from the app, and swagger logout button does no effect. (also app can read cached authorization from swagger login)

This string in properties has no effect.

```
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.sessions-stateless=true
```

Is there any way to separate work of the app and swagger - so they do not interfere each other authorization?
Thx.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: As I remember I added some custom header and extra check to my authentication filter.
And after you switch from app to swagger - the filter resets authorization

 
`if (!bearerTokenActivated & Objects.equals(refererHeader, REFERER_SWAGGER)) {
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
    }`

Comment: REFERER_SWAGGER is your swagger page url - https: //_yourdomain_/swagger-ui/index.html